# Sort nested dictionary inside a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
[ { "PricingOptions": { "Price": 51540.72, "Agents": [ 4056270 ] } }, { "PricingOptions": { "Price": 227243.14, "Agents": [ 4056270],} } ]
```

How can I sort according to Price..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = [ { "PricingOptions": { "Price": 51540.72, "Agents": [ 4056270 ] } }, { "PricingOptions": { "Price": 227243.14, "Agents": [ 4056270],} } ]
newlist = sorted(data, key=lambda k: k['PricingOptions']["Price"])
print(newlist)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'PricingOptions': {'Price': 51540.72, 'Agents': [4056270]}}, {'PricingOptions': {'Price': 227243.14, 'Agents': [4056270]}}]
```

**or** *in descending order*

```
newlist = sorted(data, key=lambda k: k['PricingOptions']["Price"], reverse=True)
print(newlist)
#[{'PricingOptions': {'Price': 227243.14, 'Agents': [4056270]}}, {'PricingOptions': {'Price': 51540.72, 'Agents': [4056270]}}]
```

Comment: My list is not in the same format, some of PricingOptions have more than one entries of [Price, Agent]. So the solution you have provided it
 will show the key error for such cases.
for example,
data =  [ { "PricingOptions": { "Price": 51540.72, "Agents": [ 4056270 ] } }, { "PricingOptions": { ["Price": 227243.14, "Agents": [ 4056270],  ["Price":454545 "Agents": [ 4056454]} } ]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sorted` method by applying a `lambda` expression.

```
sort_list = sorted(data, key=lambda elem: elem['PricingOptions']["Price"])
```

Output

```
[{'PricingOptions': {'Price': 51540.72, 'Agents': [4056270]}}, {'PricingOptions': {'Price': 227243.14, 'Agents': [4056270]}}]
```

If you want to `sort` the list descending you just need to assign `True` to `reverse` property.